# R: How to manage heading and trailing NAs when using rollmean()

Tags: r, zoo

I have this vector

```
vec <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA)
```

for which I wish to calculate a rollmean of a window of size 3 aligned to the right (that is, if I understand correctly looking backwards)

The expected rolling mean of my vector would be

```
# [1] NA NA NA  2  3  NA #
```

and yet if I do

```
rollmean(vec, 3, align='right', fill=NA)
```

I obtain

```
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: The help file for rollmean does say: "rollmean does not handle inputs that contain NAs. In such cases, use rollapply instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apply function instead.

```
rollapply(vec,3,mean,fill=NA,align="right")
[1] NA NA NA  2  3 NA
```